# Using Android Library on a Regular Java Project

Tags: java, android, class, face-detection

I am looking to use an android class on a regular non-android java project.  Specifically I want to use FaceDetector from android.media 
I know that there are OpenCV and other libraries I can use to detect a face in an image but I am looking to use androids library.  Is there a way to link androids library to a java project?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

- Go to build path of your java project
- Add a new external jar
- Browse to the location of your android platform installation
  (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Android)
- Under android-sdk\platforms\android-x (where x is the version of android you have) select the android.jar file to add to the project.

  Now you have the android library under the referenced libraries, and you can use whatever android classes you want in your java project.

Another way of doing that is to use the android source, get only the java files you need from the android library and put them into your java project. The good thing when you do it this way is that you can modify the code and make it more compatible with your java work.

Answer (score 1):

The android library might contain some calls to the system API's. Look for them before including the library with the above mentioned steps. I would recommend you to look into the documentation of the android library and look for the hooks where it calls android system APIs.Modify the source to use your webcam's API and then include it as a library

Comment: What are these calls, for example? Can i start activity in regular java project?